# Why is hovering styling not working when applied to my div?

Tags: html, css

I was looking at the site https://gradientbuttons.colorion.co/. It has some awesome examples of buttons and hovering. I tried out their examples and I could not get them to work. This is what I have:

```css
div {
  width: 90%;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fffc00 0%, #ffffff 51%, #fffc00 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, #fffc00 0%, #ffffff 51%, #fffc00 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left right, color-stop(0%,#fffc00),color-stop(51%,#ffffff ), color-stop(100%,#fffc00 ));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #fffc00 0%, #ffffff 51%, #fffc00 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to right, #fffc00 0%, #ffffff 51%, #fffc00 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(to right, #fffc00 0%, #ffffff 51%, #fffc00 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fffc00 0%, #ffffff 51%, #fffc00 100%);
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  -moz-box-shadow:
    inset 0 -3em 3em rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
    0 0  0 2px rgb(255,255,255),
    0.3em 0.3em 1em rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow:
    inset 0 -3em 3em rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
    0 0  0 2px rgb(255,255,255),
    0.3em 0.3em 1em rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow:
    inset 0 -3em 3em rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
    0 0  0 2px rgb(255,255,255),
    0.3em 0.3em 1em rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

div:hover {
  background-position: right center;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

It's not showing the animation that is shown on the website mentioned above.

Comment: Provide the ```<HTML>``` code please so that we can try to find solution

Answer (score 3):

According to their source you're missing `transition: 0.5s;` so the transition is not instantaneous, and `background-size: 200% auto;` to increase the button's background width so when it scrolls to the right it has content to display.

Using their source, here's an example of a simple button:

```css
.btn-grad {
  padding:15px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #2b5876 0%, #4e4376  51%, #2b5876  100%);
    transition: 0.5s;
    background-size: 200% auto;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #eee;
    display: block;
}
.btn-grad:hover { 
  background-position: right center; 
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-grad">Submit</button>
```

And here's your code:

```css
div {
  width: 90%;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fffc00 0%, #ffffff 51%, #fffc00 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, #fffc00 0%, #ffffff 51%, #fffc00 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left right, color-stop(0%,#fffc00),color-stop(51%,#ffffff ), color-stop(100%,#fffc00 ));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #fffc00 0%, #ffffff 51%, #fffc00 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to right, #fffc00 0%, #ffffff 51%, #fffc00 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(to right, #fffc00 0%, #ffffff 51%, #fffc00 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fffc00 0%, #ffffff 51%, #fffc00 100%);
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  -moz-box-shadow:
    inset 0 -3em 3em rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
    0 0  0 2px rgb(255,255,255),
    0.3em 0.3em 1em rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow:
    inset 0 -3em 3em rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
    0 0  0 2px rgb(255,255,255),
    0.3em 0.3em 1em rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow:
    inset 0 -3em 3em rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
    0 0  0 2px rgb(255,255,255),
    0.3em 0.3em 1em rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    transition: 0.5s;
    background-size: 200% auto;
}

div:hover {
  background-position: right center;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That did it!

Comment: Glad it did! Just in case, I edited the answer with a snippet of your code + the two missing rules.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle for those who want to play around with the code https://jsfiddle.net/qk7cpn5s/1/

Answer (score 1):

You are missing with transition: 0.5s;
    background-size: 200% auto; css properties

Answer (score 0):

Please check this. This is work on all the browsers.

```css
div {
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-size: 200% auto;
  width: 90%;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fffc00 0%, #ffffff 51%, #fffc00 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, #fffc00 0%, #ffffff 51%, #fffc00 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left right, color-stop(0%,#fffc00),color-stop(51%,#ffffff ), color-stop(100%,#fffc00 ));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #fffc00 0%, #ffffff 51%, #fffc00 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to right, #fffc00 0%, #ffffff 51%, #fffc00 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(to right, #fffc00 0%, #ffffff 51%, #fffc00 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fffc00 0%, #ffffff 51%, #fffc00 100%);
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  -moz-box-shadow:
    inset 0 -3em 3em rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
    0 0  0 2px rgb(255,255,255),
    0.3em 0.3em 1em rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow:
    inset 0 -3em 3em rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
    0 0  0 2px rgb(255,255,255),
    0.3em 0.3em 1em rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow:
    inset 0 -3em 3em rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
    0 0  0 2px rgb(255,255,255),
    0.3em 0.3em 1em rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

div:hover {
  background-position: right center;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```